# Why is scrapy always returning the same value?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to python 3 and I'm trying to understand how Scrapy works.

My question may be very basic but I wrote the following script and what I want is the value of a share on the stock market for every day in the last month.

Scrapy always returns the value of the last day but 28th time..

can you help me to get where is my mistake ?

Thanks a lot.

```js
import scrapy

class CoursSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cours'
    start_urls = ['https://www.boursorama.com/cours/historique/1rPAI']

    def parse(self, response):
        for cours in response.xpath('//table[@class="c-table"]/tbody[@class="c-table__body"]/tr[@class="c-table__row"]'):
            yield {
                    'Valeur': cours.xpath('//td[@class="c-table__cell c-table__cell--dotted"][2]/text()').extract_first(),
                    'Date': cours.xpath('//td[@class="c-table__cell c-table__cell--dotted"][1]/text()').extract_first(),
                   }
```

Comment: You missed a dot ***.*** in your xpath. Try replacing `'//td[@class="c-table__cell c-table__cell--dotted"][2]/text()'` with `'.//td[@class="c-table__cell c-table__cell--dotted"][2]/text()'`. Do the same for the date as well.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough therefor I can not get you the right code. However, based on what I see in your code I can tell you need to edit your selectors to point to the right tag.

Comment: the best way to figure it is to use scrapy shell (test your selectors there)

Comment: @SIM Thanks a lot ! That was just the point.. i'm so happy that this code works ! Have a nice day.